# How to create a TableViewCell with multiple UICollectionViews within it?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

Hi I'm currently attempting to create a very complex TableViewCell which will be used once and presented at the top of our TableView. The view consists of 
4x `UILabel`
2x `UICollectionView`
1x `UIImage`

I'm wondering whether this is feasible and what the best way to approach this is?
[image]

I'm open to this not being a `UITableViewCell` but we want this to seamlessly scroll with the rest of the TableView, putting this within its own container above the TableView and within a `UIScrollView` was pretty messy as we had to handle the scrolling for both the scroll view and the tableview.

Comment: My first attempt followed a popular tutorial but the architecture didn't appear appropriate as it delegates the CollectionViews to the TableViewController this is part of (the tutorial dedicates an entire row to each collectionview) and XCode would not allow me to place `UICollectionViewCell`s in to my `UICollectionView`s.

Comment: My 2nd attempt has involved creating a storyboard using a 2nd `UITableViewController` with a single prototype cell containing the whole view but this doesn't appear to load and crashes if I modify any of the IBOutlets.

Comment: Is this image actually representative of your goal? You say it has 2x `UICollectionView` ... does one contain the meeting times, and the other contains the photos? Are those going to need to scroll? Or "wrap" onto multiple lines?

Comment: @DonMag Yes it is. They will only use one line but will need to scroll when there's more content than can fit on the screen.

Comment: Have you considered using this as the tableHeaderView? Probably easier than mixing it in with the rest of the table (I'm assuming you have a bunch of rows...)

Comment: Re-reading your comments... Is part of the problem having all the CollectionView code in the same Controller as the TableView code? And things get messy, or it's not working?

Comment: @DonMag I've not come across a tableHeaderView I'll have a look in to it. Part of the problem is having collectionview code in the tableviewcontroller but it also doesn't work. I may be able to get it working (I'll be trying tomorrow)  but I'd like to do this as cleanly as possible so I'm mostly looking for the best approach rather than getting one of my many attempts to work with the prospect of future technical debt/ refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - my suggestion would be...

- Create a new ViewController - `MyHeaderViewController`
- Layout this view, including the 2x `UICollectionView`
- Get it working on its own

Once you've got that part going...

- Create a new ViewController (can be a UITableViewController, or a UIViewController with a UITableView added)
- add code in this controller to load `MyHeaderViewController`, and then set the tableHeaderView = myHeaderVC.view

That let's you keep all the logic for the Collection Views separate from the TableView

See https://github.com/DonMag/SWTableHeaderView for a simple example.

Comment: Would `MyHeaderViewController` use a xib or a storyboard?

Comment: You could design it in a xib or in your storyboard. Depending on how complex your app is... Like, do you already have 30 Controllers in your storyboard? If so, you might be better off using a separate xib (or adding another storyboard). If not, then creating it in your current storyboard is probably easier.

Comment: I use Swift 3 .

Comment: @Deco - If you're still looking at this, I put up a simple example that you might find helpful at https://github.com/DonMag/SWTableHeaderView

Comment: That's a really impressive example, thanks for taking the time to write that up. I had no idea you could add Views that aren't `UITableViewCells` to a TableView.